# How to save information related to post in database?

Tags: plugins, php, database

I created a post-to-email plugin and I need to save something in the database when the post is sent so I don't allow users to send it twice.

How do I save this in the database? And how can I retrieve it later?

Comment: "I don't allow users" - as in the post author, or a possibly-logged-in reader? i.e. do you need a single flag per post, or a flag-per-user-per-post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about post meta ?

```
if ( ! update_post_meta (7, 'sent', '1') ) { 
    add_post_meta(7, 'sent', '1', true );   
};
```

[add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)

Or options table or custom table